# regex adding a special character if the quantifier condition is respected

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, quantifiers

**Input**

R34, I9012, A39, A, A3939, X9393, B9393939393, B39, A3

**Desired Output**

R34, I90.12, A39, A, A39.39, X93.93, B93.93939393, B39, A3

**Explanation**

I would like to add a dot after 3 characters only if the element of the list contains 4 character or more (so for instance I want to get "I90.12" but I dont want to get "R34." ) .

**Partial regex to the solution**

I can detect the elements that needs to be modified with the following:

```
([A-Za-z])\w{3,}
```

but I still can't get the final output I wish to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following *regex* :

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})(\w+)
```

and replace the match with the captured groups `$1.$2`

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Zp6IWc/1)**